# Using Grep on txt file to find 7 letter words that start with the same letter

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

```
grep -i "^(.).*\1$" sowpods.txt > output.txt
```

I'm using a scrabble words list I downloaded named "sowpods.txt" and I am trying to use grep to find all of the 7 letter words in the file that start and end with the same letter .The line I have now is giving me a backreference error so I tried using online guides but they were insanely confusing. Could someone help me do this? Thanks!

I'm also on a mac and am using the default terminal.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SE to distribute that content. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please take a look at: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use *basic* regular expression (without option `-E`), you need a backslash `\` before the opening and closing brackets:

```
grep -i '^\(.\).\{5\}\1$' file
```

Note that it's good idea to use single quote in your grep regex in order to avoid shell parameter expansion.

Answer (score 2):

This will work as an extended regular expression. You need `grep -E`:

```
grep -E -i "^(.).*\1$"
```

To match 7-letter words you need to replace `*` with `{5}`:

```
grep -E -i "^(.).{5}\1$"
```

Comment: I'm a fan of the `-x` flag: `grep -Eix "(.).{5}\1"`