# `grep` to find words with several criteria (for scrabble)

Tags: command-line, mac, grep

I'm using a scrabble words list I downloaded named "sowpods.txt" and I am trying to use `grep` to find all of words with these criteria:

- 7 letter word
- Starts and ends with the same letter
- Has the same second ,fourth, and sixth letter
- Has a different 3rd and 5th letter

The line I have so far

```
grep -i "^(.).*\1$" sowpods.txt > output.txt
```

is giving me a backreference error so I tried using online guides but they were insanely confusing. Is this even possible? If so could someone please help?

I'm on a Mac and am using the default terminal.

Comment: Your [previous question](https://superuser.com/q/1356890/432690) showed you need `grep -E` or to escape parentheses. This should get rid of the backreference error, you will be able to continue now. Why are you asking about (partially) the same issue? Don't the solutions to the other question work on Mac? If they don't, the right thing to do is to give feedback to users who tried to help you there and solve the other question first, instead of raising the same issue for the second time.

Comment: Ah, I did not understand that the E was the problem, I just put in the line that they had given me. Although I actually do not know where to go from the line of code I have now :(.

Comment: OK then. If the other question is solved then please accept one of the answers there (take our [tour] to see how it works). You should also [edit] the current question so it doesn't mention the "backreference error", because you know how to cope with it and it's no longer the issue (nor a part of the issue); concentrate on whatever the real issue is *now*. If the "backreference error" was your *only* issue then this question should be deleted or at least closed as a duplicate of the other one.

Comment: Can the second letter be the same as the first? Can the third be the same as the second? ... Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1366807/edit) and add test cases.

Answer (score 1):

Using `-P` option (PCRE) if available on your system:

```
grep -P '^(?=[a-zA-Z]{7}$)(.)(?!\1)(.)(?!\1)(?!\2)(.)\2(?!\1)(?!\2)(?!\3).\2\1$' inputfile
```

**Explanation:**

```
^
  (?=[a-zA-Z]{7}$)  : positive lookahead, zero-length assertion that make sure we have exactly 7 letters. You may use \pL{7} if you want to deal with any laguage
  (.)               : first letter, captured in group 1
  (?!\1)            : negative lookahead, zero-length assertion that make sure we don't have the same letter as in group 1 after
  (.)               : second letter, captured in group 2
  (?!\1)            : negative lookahead, zero-length assertion that make sure we don't have the same letter as in group 1 after
  (?!\2)            : negative lookahead, zero-length assertion that make sure we don't have the same letter as in group 2 after
  (.)               : third letter, captured in group 3
  \2                : fourth letter == second letter
  (?!\1)            : negative lookahead, zero-length assertion that make sure we don't have the same letter as in group 1 after
  (?!\2)            : negative lookahead, zero-length assertion that make sure we don't have the same letter as in group 2 after
  (?!\3)            : negative lookahead, zero-length assertion that make sure we don't have the same letter as in group 3 after
  .                 : fifth letter
  \2                : sixth letter == second letter
  \1                : seventh letter == first letter
$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/m6Ogy2/1)